# Magento Indexing taking so much time to complete

Tags: performance, magento, reindex

I have imported more than 10M products and i am trying to index it. When i tried to index it taking so much time especially **"Catalog URL Rewrites, Product Flat Data, Catalog Search Index"** . Is there is any way that i can perform indexing on those products ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: D'oh! 10 million products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

" Is there is any way that i can perform indexing on those products ?" If you run this from the browser and get some 50x errors (usually PHP has different timeouts for web and cli) then you can run the indexer from command line (check php.ini first for an optimal Magento configuration - memory and no timeout): php shell/indexer.php help

The indexer on Magento takes a long time, depending on the number of Products and Store Views you have (Attributes, Categories... but mainly the two above).
If you use the Enterprise version of Magento you have a SOLR module that can be used for search and layered navigation (usually faster than MySQL). In the latest Enterprise version some tweaks were made to avoid certain bugs, so maybe using 13.0.1 will help you.

Also having good hardware helps a lot (database on SSDs)

Anyway for 10M products the indexing could take ~ 50-80h multiplied by the number of Store Views you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you can SSH into the server, then navigate yourself to the `shell` folder (located in the root of your Magento installation) and run the following:

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Using the above, I've re-indexed a catalog of 100,000+ products in 60 - 90 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

magento programatically re index ID Code

1 catalog_product_attribute

2 catalog_product_price

3 catalog_url

4 catalog_product_flat

5 catalog_category_flat

6 catalog_category_product

7 catalogsearch_stock

8 cataloginventory_stock

9 tag_summary

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {

$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);

$process->reindexAll();

}